# How do I block file transfer to USB devices except for USB headphones?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I want to block USB file transfer in my Ubuntu OS, but I am using USB headphones - so I want to block only file transfer to USB pendrives.

How do I block file transfer to USB devices except for USB headphones?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:
`sudo  mv /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko  /root`

This will move usb-storage.ko to root folder

```
sudo gedit /etc/modeprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add `balcklist usb_storage` at bottom of the page, save and exit

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

add `modprobe -r usb_storage` before **exit0**, save and exit
reboot your computer and check usb storage is mounting or not

Comment: This is assuming that you have Ubuntu 12.X version.